# Proper Method of Creating Daily-Building PPAs

Tags: ppa, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prepare autoupdating PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52475/how-to-prepare-autoupdating-ppa)

Is there a proper method that works to create a daily automatic build of a PPA in Launchpad?  If so, what is the proper methodology?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is through Launchpad recipes. The main documentation for recipes is at https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes.

Matt Revell also posted a nice introduction youtube video when recipes were first announced that I would recommend watching: http://blog.launchpad.net/cool-new-stuff/source-package-recipes