# How should I package my sources so Launchpad build my package for all versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I have a package that should build for all versions of Ubuntu, so I hope that Launchpad builds all of them... well, it doesn't. I submitted just using `trusty` in the changelog release field, and Launchpad build it for Trusty. I changed it for `precise` and just built for Precise. Is there a way I can use the same sources for several release target?

```
ffc (1.3.20140513-1) trusty; urgency=medium

  * Non-maintainer upload.
  * Moving to git.
  * Syncronized debian/* with upstream

 -- redacted <redacted@example.com>  Fri, 16 May 2014 16:15:00 -0400
```

Comment: If your package has no different requirements or different build depends, you can just use the Copy packages link and copy to different Ubuntu release in Launchpad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

There is currently no way to use `dput` to upload a package that builds for multiple Ubuntu releases. However, you can accomplish your goal using one of these two methods:

#### Create a Recipe

If you are building a package from a branch on Launchpad and you have Debian packaging, create a daily build recipe that targets the Ubuntu releases you wish to support. This is described in more detail in the latter half of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/52478/5).

This is really the best solution since it also automates new builds every time you make a change (with a limit on one automatic build per day, although you can manually dispatch additional builds).

#### Upload Multiple Builds Manually

This is not an ideal solution - but it works. What you need to do to make this work is:

- Adjust the version number in the changelog to match this format:

  ```
  [version]-1ppa1~[release]1
  ```

  ...where `[version]` is the package version and `[release]` is an Ubuntu release codename (like `trusty`, `saucy`, etc.).
- Make sure the changelog is set to build the correct release. In other words, for Trusty, the first line of your changelog should look like this:

  ```
  ffc (1.3.20140513-1ppa1~trusty1) trusty; urgency=medium
  ```

Upload the package using `dput` and then repeat the two steps above for each release you want to upload packages for. You can see an example of how this works [here](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/openssl-heartbleed-fix).

Comment: You could probably add that the `dput` method requires that you upload to the `ubuntu/<suite>` directory, as described [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading#Using_packages_from_other_distributions).